# UINavigationBar custom font not working on iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uinavigationbar

I've spent some hours trying to use a custom font for the navigation bar title on iOS 8. This works ok on iOS 7:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Gotham-Bold" size:12];
NSDictionary *textAttributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName: font };
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes;
```

But on iOS 8 the text simply disappears. Changing the color, or the system font size works perfectly, but trying to use a custom font won't work at all. Anyone has any idea on this?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I've created a small project so you can try it yourself:
https://github.com/noquepoaqui/customHeaderFont

These lines of code are on MasterViewController on line 30.

Comment: Where do you execute this code? Better approach would be to use UIAppearance proxy and change it application wide

Comment: I've also tried it with `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleAttributes:textAttributes];` and get the same result

Comment: Can it be related to the custom font? Can you try customize it using one of the default fonts?

Comment: I tried with georgia and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo when you assign the attributes:

It should be:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes
```

instead of:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.TitleTextAttributes
```

If that doesn't fix the issue, you can test if the font was added correctly by placing this code in the AppDelegate's `didFinishLoadingWithOptions`. This will print all available fonts of your app. Just look at the output window and search for your font name (Gotham-Bold). If it's not listed you can delete the font from your project and add it again via drag & drop. Make sure to tick "add to target" next to your app in the dialog that appears.

```
//list all available fonts
for (NSString *family in [UIFont familyNames]) {
    NSLog(@"---------- %@ ----------", family.uppercaseString);
    NSArray *names = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:family];
    for (NSString *font in names) NSLog(@"%@", font);
}
```

Comment: the font is in the list, i use it in other parts of the application, i just can't make it work on the navbar title

Comment: can you make a sample project with a single navigationviewcontroller and replicate the issue? could you post a link to your sample project if it has the same issue?

Comment: I've edited my question adding a link to a github page with the sample project.

Answer (score 0):

The .ttf font i was using was not working well. I've installed the .otf version and everything works well.